# Check transition finish

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a transition. I just expand it with some easing. The when hovered changes its `background-color` and when we move the mouse out of it changes its `background-color` again! But I want the background-color to revert back when the transition gets finished. How can I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="userWidget">
    <div class="user">
        <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>
        <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="userWidget">
    <div class="user">
        <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>
        <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="userWidget">
    <div class="user">
        <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>
        <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="userWidget">
    <div class="user">
        <img src="img/user.png" width="50" height="50" />   <span class="name">Danish</span>
        <br/>   <span class="skills">Coder, Programmer</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.userWidget {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
.userWidget:hover {
    z-index: 2;
}
.user {
    position: absolute; 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s;
}
.user:hover {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0.5s, height 0.3s ease 0.5s, background-color 2.3s;
    background: #eee;
}
.user img {
    float: left;
}
.user .name, .skills {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.user .name {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuCML/).

As you can see in the fiddle the going back transition is just making it weird! How do I revert back the `background-color` to `#fff` when the transition finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's better to use keyframe animation instead of transition ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PuCML/4/))?

```
.user:hover {
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0.5s, height 0.3s ease 0.5s;
    animation: flash 2.5s ease .8s forwards;
}

@keyframes flash {
    0% { background: #fff; }
    80% { background: #eee; }
    100% { background: #fff; }
}
```

Comment: it's not working, the background-color is changed from the beginning now! :(

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong order of sub-properties in the 'animation' syntax. See edit and the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/PuCML/6/

Comment: still, I want the #eee to come when we hover over the div and go when the div comes back to its original size!

Comment: Sorry again, it seems I completely misunderstood the task:( Probably you just need to add 'background' to transition value for .user (non-hovered): http://jsfiddle.net/PuCML/7/?